# What's the easiest way to point a subdomain in Rails to a specific controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

For example, http://foo.myapp.com/bar/23 would render FooController#bar.

Comment: Edited for clarity. Thanks for those suggestions, but they don't seem to do what I'd like (or I'm not paying attention enough).

Comment: Found the request_routing plugin, which seems to do what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the plugin [subdomain_fu](http://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu/tree/master)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [subdomain_fu](http://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu/) for quite a while. Recently I discovered [subdomain_routes](http://github.com/mholling/subdomain_routes/) that seems to be a really powerful alternative.

Comment: For some reason the subdomain_routes link doesn't work. Adding a / on the end seems to fix.

Comment: Thanks Shadwell, I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [subdomain_routes](http://github.com/mholling/subdomain_routes/) with complex routing and it appears to make the application very slow.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3.2, one can route subdomains easily in the routes.rb file.

```
constraints :subdomain => 'foo' do
  resources :bar
end
```